# A value according to time period Excel Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to add a value to a cell according to time interval,
Values are: "Day Shift" and "Night Shift"

if current time is between 06:00 am and 06:00 pm then type in cell "Day Shift", and if current time is between 06:00 pm and 06:00 am then type in cell "Night Shift"

I work as waiter, so I'm not a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following formula in a cell:

```
=IF(AND(HOUR(NOW()) >= 6, HOUR(NOW()) <= 18),"Day Shift","Night Shift")
```

Be aware that `Now` (the current time) and so your formula will only be updated,
when you select it and hit <kbd>F9</kbd>.